# I want to draw these progress indicators in flutter. Is this possible in flutter? I face many difficulties while making this.Please help me

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

1st image:

[image]

2nd image:

[image]

In these pictures all colors represents progresses.

I have tried [multi_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_circular_slider) package and other packages like that!

Comment: provide more details

Comment: You haven't uploaded the picture. You have just typed 1st image and 2nd image but not attached the actual image.

Comment: you can use CustomPaint

Comment: I have to show some calculations in form of UI above. In UI pink color represents days in months, red color represents next period duration(it is a duration eg:- 12-17 days) , blue color represents safe days(duration).